# how to set center a button on screen - native base

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I'm using button of native base library.

this is whole my codes:

```
  <LinearGradient
      start={{x: 0.0, y: 0.1}} end={{x: 0.5, y: 1.0}}
      locations={[0.2,0.23,0.9]}
      colors={[randomColor1,randomColor1, randomColor2]}
      style={{flex:1,height:'100%',width:'100%',flexDirection: 'column'}}>

      <View style={{width:'100%',height:'100%',flexDirection:'column',flex:1}}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'column',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:22,marginTop:20,color:'#fff',fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'center'}}>Powerful Composition</Text>
          <Button style={{textAlign:'center',justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center',paddingLeft:40,paddingRight:40,marginTop:10,height:40}} light><Text style={{textAlign:'center'}}> JOIN </Text></Button>
        </View>

        <Text style={{fontSize:18,marginTop:20,color:'#fff',fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'center',position:'absolute',left:0,bottom:0,marginLeft:6,marginBottom:6}}>607.8 K Votes</Text>

        <Text style={{fontSize:18,marginTop:20,color:'#fff',fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'center',position:'absolute',right:0,bottom:0,marginLeft:6,marginBottom:6,marginRight:4}}>9 Days Left</Text>

      </View>


  </LinearGradient>
```

my `Text` is center of screen. but the `Button` that is below of it is at the left screen!

where is my wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add the style `alignSelf: 'center'` to the  styles

```
<Button style={{alignSelf:'center',{/*Other Styles*/}}}> JOIN </Text></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `justifyContent: 'center'` if `AlignSelf` doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of passing a `Text` element to your `Button` component you should use the `title` prop

```
<Button 
  style={{
    textAlign:'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingLeft:40,
    paddingRight:40,
    marginTop:10,
    height:40
  }}
  light
  title="JOIN"
/>
```

You can see in [this snack](https://snack.expo.io/HyHZwehu7) the button is centered

Comment: Not supported by native base library as asked by the author.